Are there Bluetooth dongle's with pairing buttons widely available?
I receive a "Link Dream" BH60 bluetooth headset as a gift, which comes with a very handy Bluetooth dongle which has a physical button for pairing.  So that by pressing the pairing button on the dongle and the headset they'll pair -- remarkably simple.
Is this a common technology?  Is the dongle universal to other Bluetooth devices, or will it only work with this device?  I haven't had a chance to try it on Linux, but this seems remarkably convenient.
Looks like a great work-around to sound and Bluetooth problems on Linux, but I can't find the dongle by itself.

It seems like a custom extension, that dongle could even use custom protocol and not Bluetooth. Anyway, pairing on the computer involves selecting what device you want to pair. The button doesn't make sense in general use, which of dozens of devices in range will it pair with?

The switch has three positions:  custom,on,off.  With custom, it seems to pair exclusively with the dongle.  With "on" I can pair a cell phone normally.  And, of course, off is self explanatory.

A friend of mine created a dogle that could connect to a specific device when you plug in.
It's an nRF52840 dongle that you can configure.
I never have the opportunity to try it myself but I can give you some basic documentation that I found.
Using the app
For development
